# Standard name for a Monoid/Semigroup with $a+b \leq a, b$?

Tags: lattices, semigroups-and-monoids

I have seen suplattice and inflattice being used when dealing with a lattice. What about when you don't have a lattice?

For instance, for reals $a,b > 0$, define $$a \oplus b = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}},$$ you have a semigroup, also $a \oplus b \leq a, b$ because
\begin{align*}
a \oplus b & = \frac{ab}{a+b} = a\bigg(\frac{b}{a+b}\bigg) < a \quad \text{(since $a,b>0$).}
\end{align*}
I am tempted to just call this an infsemigroup. (This can be a monoid if we include infinity as the identity element).

Comment: For a monoid this is the same as being a pomonoid in which the identity is maximum. These have been extensively studied in connection with J-trivial monoids. In quantale theory if the identity is max then I think the quantale is called 2-sided.

Comment: Wait, according to this, isn't a J-trivial monoid exactly what I asked about? The definition here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.3455v3.pdf has: "a monoid M is J -trivial provided that there exists a partial ordering ≤
on M such that for all x, y ∈ M, one has xy ≤ x and xy ≤ y"

Comment: This is wrong. This condition implies J-triviality and every finite J-trivial monoid is a quotient of such an ordered monoid.

Comment: Perhaps a simpler example is the real interval [0, 1] with ⊕ being the standard multiplication and the identity element being 1. Anyway, have you found a suitable name for it?

Comment: I'm tempted to call it a _downward semigroup_, because a⊕b≤a,b implies that the underlying set is [_downward directed_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set). Analogously, a posemigroup with a,b≤a⊕b would be called _upward semigroup_ (because it is _upward directed_). /cc @BenjaminSteinberg